# can HTML5 communicate with Java Serversocketchannel?

Tags: html, websocket

can HTML5 communicate with Java Serversocketchannel?
if possible can anyone tellme the details.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are talking about [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets) and not some other protocol (Flash, Java applet and Silverlight native sockets, or XMLHttpRequest connections). WebSockets are an HTTP family spec from IETF and not related directly to HTML5 (though they are both in the extended family of next-gen web standards).

Browser WebSocket implementations can only talk to servers that deliberately support the WebSocket protocol. You can certainly write a server that supports the WebSocket protocol using a ServerSocketChannel, but WebSocket will not be able to connect to an arbitrary service that was written (using ServerSocketChannel or not) without the WebSocket protocol in mind.

This is a deliberate security measure to prevent web browsers being forced to connect to non-web-related services (eg to port 25 to send spam).

If you want to write a WebSocket protocol layer on top of ServerSocketChannel you'll need to put a non-trivial amount of work into implementing [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). It would seem more sensible to re-use [an existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278456/websockets-production-ready-server-in-java).