# Eclipse javax.websocket import not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket

I'm new to Java development (using it for speeding up my real-time game server, coming from Python).

I'm trying to add some basic Java server-side websockets, and added the simplest example code I found (from [WebSockets production ready server in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278456/websockets-production-ready-server-in-java)).

I'm importing the following:

[image]

My problem is, eclipse is telling me that the **import "javax.websocket" cannot be resolved**. Where I can add the "javax" module? I don't understand the complicated interface fully yet, thanks a lot for any help! (I've got the latest eclipse, with Java 8 installed on Mac os X 10.11 latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use JDK or Java EE? `javax.websocket` is in [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).